# To bring the selected records from the table to the controller Get method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

I am trying to bring all the column values like 'RegNo','Customer', 'FleetDate' from the selected rows of the table from the Javascript function EditbreakDown. Currently selected values is passed only if the controller method is HttpPost method. I need to bring all the above value to the method having HttpGet. If I change HttpPost into HttpGet, the value from Javascript will not be passed. Someone can help me how can bring to the HttpGet method in controller SummaryReport. Here is the code

```
public class FleetSummViewModel
{
  public string CustomerCode { get; set; }        
  public string Depot { get; set; }
  public string FleetNo { get; set; }
  public string RegNo { get; set; } 
  public string FleetDate { get; set; }      
} 
[HttpGet]
 public IActionResult SummaryReport(List<FleetSummViewModel> fleets)
 {
 }

 
<button type="button" name="submitButton" value="Edit" class="btn btn-primary form-control"
         onclick="EditbreakDown()">
         Edit
</button>
                        
function EditbreakDown() {
        var fleets = []; // create an empty array to hold the report objects
        var selectedRows = table.rows('.selected').nodes(); // get an array of the selected row nodes
        $(selectedRows).each(function() {
            var fleet = {}; // create a new report object for each selected row
            fleet.CustomerCode = table.cell(this, 0).data(); // assign the column data to the report object
            fleet.RegNo = table.cell(this, 2).data();
            fleet.FleetNo = table.cell(this, 3).data();
            fleet.FleetDate = table.cell(this, 4).data();
            fleets.push(fleet);
           
        })

         $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "/FleetCheck/SummaryReport",
            //dataType: "json",
            data: {fleets:fleets},
            success: function (response) {
                console.log("dfgdfg");
            },
            error: function (response) {
                var misinfo = ('@ViewBag.Result');
                console.log(misinfo);
            }
        });      
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Currently selected values is passed only if the controller method is
> HttpPost method. I need to bring all the above value to the method
> having HttpGet. If I change HttpPost into HttpGet, the value from
> Javascript will not be passed. Someone can help me how can bring to
> the HttpGet method in controller SummaryReport.

Generally, to send list kind of object in controller HttpPost would always be the good option considering all the aspects. But as you are determind to send it through HttpGet; Thus, this won't be good practice but you can still send request using HttpGet.

To achieve that, you have to stringify your fleets object and at the same time you need to set string parameter as of your controller argument. Once you would receive the value passed as your controller argument then you would require to Deserialize that string into your List class.

Let's check that in action.

Controller:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult SummaryReport(string fleets)
        {
            List<FleetSummViewModel> retrieveObjeect = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FleetSummViewModel>>(fleets);
            return Ok(retrieveObjeect.Take(3));
        }
```

HTML:

```
<button type="button" name="submitButton" value="Edit" class="btn btn-primary form-control"
        onclick="EditbreakDown()">
    Edit
</button>
```

Javascript:

```
@section scripts {
    <script>
        function EditbreakDown() {

            alert("Working");

            var fleets = [];
            for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                var items = {
                    CustomerCode: "CustomerCode:" + i,
                    RegNo: "RegNo:" + i,
                    FleetNo: "FleetNo:" + i,

                }
                fleets.push(items);

               
            }

            console.log(fleets);

            var json = JSON.stringify(fleets);

            console.log(json);
            var url = '@Url.Action("SummaryReport","FleetCheck")';
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "GET",
                datatype: "JSON",
                data: { fleets: json },
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
}
```

**Note:** Here, I am using my self defined object to enqueue the fleets array. In your scenario, you would replace this with your `var selectedRows = table.rows('.selected').nodes()` table  rows. then stringify the object.

Output:

[image]

**Note:** Please be informed that, [HttpGet has the request limit](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/maximum-url-length-is-2-083-characters-in-internet-explorer-174e7c8a-6666-f4e0-6fd6-908b53c12246). Once it exceeds the limit you may encounter null request or request filtering can blocks the request as the request exceeds the request limits which may through 404.15 error code as well. [More can be found here in our official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits/).